# Search with inequalities on string property

Tags: nhibernate

We are using NHibernate over SQL Server and SQLite.
The database stores records in rows rather than columns -- each row having `Path|Value` as columns. Path and Value are both `string` properties.

For certain values of `Path` we would like to query for inequalities -- greater-than, less-than, etc.

The trouble we are having is that because the properties are strings, the inequalities are using string comparisons -- for example, searching for `Value >= 18` returns rows where `Value = 5`.  Unfortunately we are having trouble working around this.

1) This restriction produces incorrect results (saying `18 < 5`):

`Restrictions.Ge("Value", item.Value);`

2) We tried casting the value to an integer, but this code produces a `SqlException` from NHibernate -- `Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.`

`Restrictions.Le(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.Int64, Projections.Property("SearchString")), item.Value)`

3) We were looking for a way to pad the property value with zeros (so that we would get `018 > 005`), but could not find a way to do this in NHibernate.

Does anyone have any advice?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to compare on integer value, with `IQueryOver`:

> 1) This restriction produces incorrect results (saying 18 < 5):
>
> `Restrictions.Ge("Value", item.Value);`

```
Restrictions.Ge
    (
    Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.Property<YourEntity>(x => x.YourProperty))
        , intValue
    )
```

Convert your datatype accordingly. If your C# datatype (`intValue`) is already numeric, no need to convert it. If your `x.YourProperty` is already numeric type, no need to convert it. Adjust above code accordingly.

> 2) We tried casting the value to an integer, but this code produces a SqlException from `NHibernate -- Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.`
>
> `Restrictions.Le(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.Int64, Projections.Property("SearchString")), item.Value)`

Refer the above and check the datatype of `item.Value`.